# Does too much data binding make WPF application slow? What are the optimization techniques that are available?

Tags: wpf, optimization, mvvm, binding

I have completed a project on WPF? I wanted to know which are the possible techniques to optimize my code especially XAML and Data binding. 
Tricks to have efficient data binding. 
Please note I am using MVVM architecture.

Comment: That's a "hook" title if I've ever seen one. You aren't actually asking *if* WPF makes your application slow, you're wondering if there are any optimization techniques for WPF and databinding.

Comment: It wasn't necessarily a *negative* comment so much as a tongue-in-cheek one. But the edit does make your question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN contains a nice WPF optimisation article here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx, with a section specifically on data binding here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx